# Derivation of the total received field in ground reflection model

Tags: waves, electromagnetic-radiation, electric-fields, antennas

I am reading [this](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/0470841524) book by J.D. Parsons.

The problem concerned, is how to find the  propagation model for propagation over a curved reflecting surfac, i.e.: [image]

I would like to know where is the Equation for the total field strength taken from. (The one between 2.18 and 2.19). There is no reference and I cannot quite understand it. Thanks.[image]

Comment: This is one of those books where $j$ is the imaginary unit, correct?

Comment: Yes. $j=\sqrt(-1)$

Answer (score 0):

The total electric field at the receiver is the *sum* of the direct component $E_d$ and the reflected component. When the reflected component reflects off the ground, its magnitude changes from $E_d$ (the same as the direct component) to $\rho E_d$ (where $\rho<1$). But since the reflected component traveled a different distance than the direct component, it also is at a different *phase* than the direct component, and the two out-of-phase waves can *interfere* at the receiver.

In particular, if $\Delta\phi=0$, then the two waves constructively interfere, directly adding, so $E=E_d+\rho E_d$. In contrast, if $\Delta\phi=\pi$, then the two waves destructively interfere, directly subtracting, so that $E=E_d-\rho E_d$. In general, for intermediate $\Delta\phi$, the magnitude of the sum of the two out-of-phase signals is $E=E_d+\rho E_d\cos(\Delta\phi)$, which is just the real part of $E=E_d+\rho E_de^{-j\Delta\phi}$, the expression given in your book.